# How to customize LXPanel/LXSession for a VNC connection

Tags: vnc, lxde

I would like to have two different desktop configurations based on whether I am sitting at my RPi or connected through a VNC.  I've got remote access set up according to [these instructions](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/) and I have done nothing to the default window environment other than add a second panel and a few desktop shortcuts.

I would like to have a minimal and separate desktop configuration for the VNC connection.  I have perused the general information on [lxsession](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXSession) and [lxpanel](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/LXPanel) on the LXDE wiki page; however it's not clear to me how I tell the VNC (at startup with the `vncserver :2 -geometry...` or perhaps in `$HOME/.vnc/xstartup`) that I want a different profile to be used.

Answer (score 1):

One solution, which I do not find very elegant, is to create a new user and start `vncserver` under that account.  The benefits of this approach is that it avoids messing with the configuration files (and, at present, it's the only way I've gotten it to work...); however I suspect it will not be of much assistance when I move from a test-bed (starting the server when needed) to a production-level solution (starting the server at boot).